# View listing A filtering on B with a reference B -> A

Tags: views, nodes

Here's my problem : I have a view that lists nodes of type A (A = tips). In my Drupal, I have another content type B (B = vegetables), which has a multiple node reference with A.

So, what I want is a filter in my view, which is a select on all the nodes B. When the user select a B node, the view should display all the nodes A which are related to B, depending on the field multilple node reference in B.

I tried with relations, exposed form alter and query alter, but I can't achieve that, and I'm getting a little bit confused with that...

How could I do that ? 
Thanks.

EDIT: more informations !
I don't think it can works with relations, because when I print the SQL request of the view, I can see that it's doing it the wrong way. For example, I add a relation in my view on the field "Preparation tips" in B (= vegetables). Here's the left join the views does :

`SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.language AS node_language, node.created AS node_created, 'node' AS field_data_field_tip_main_picture_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_vegetable_preparation_tips} field_data_field_vegetable_preparation_tips ON node.nid = field_data_field_vegetable_preparation_tips.entity_id AND (field_data_field_vegetable_preparation_tips.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_vegetable_preparation_tips.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN {node} node_field_data_field_vegetable_preparation_tips ON field_data_field_vegetable_preparation_tips.field_vegetable_preparation_tips_nid = node_field_data_field_vegetable_preparation_tips.nid
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('tip')) ))
ORDER BY node_created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0`

That's why it doesn't work : `ON node.nid = field_data_field_vegetable_preparation_tips.entity_id`. field_data_field_vegetable_preparation_tips.entity_id contains Vegetables ids, not Tips ids. Maybe I don't set the good relation in my view ? I don't know...

Comment: It looks like it should simply work with views and relations. Show us a screen of your config (only the part related), and the effect you got. Your approach seems right, so if it fails, it's somewhere in the way you executed it, not in the way you designed it.

Comment: I've added more details in my post.